# How can one argue that the partial transpose $\rho^{T_B}$ of a general separable state is positive?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, density-matrix, linear-algebra, partial-transpose

How can one argue that the partial transpose $\rho^{T_B}$ of a general separable state is positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that if $R$ and $S$ are positive (aka positive semi-definite) operators and $q\in [0, +\infty)$ then $R^T$, $qR$, $R\otimes S$ and $R+S$ are all positive operators.

By definition, if $\rho_{AB}$ is separable then there exist positive operators $\rho_{i,A}$ and $\sigma_{i,B}$ with unit trace and $p_i\in[0, 1]$ such that

$$
\rho_{AB} = \sum_i p_i \rho_{i,A}\otimes\sigma_{i,B}.
$$

Thus, the partial transpose

$$
\rho_{AB}^{T_B} = \sum_i p_i \rho_{i,A}\otimes\sigma_{i,B}^T
$$

is a sum of tensor products of positive operators and therefore is itself positive.